# flex_color_picker-2.3.0 throwing error since the plugin is used in html_editor_enhanced plugin

Tags: flutter

When I try to run the application getting this error.

```
../tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flex_color_picker-2.3.0/lib/src/widgets/color_picker_toolbar.dart:113:44: Error: The argument type 'double?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double' because 'double?' is nullable and 'double' isn't.
              iconSize: effectiveIconTheme.size,
```

Directly am not using this plugin. But one of the plugin([https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor_enhanced](https://plugin)) is using this library. So not able to figure it out how to fix it.

It was working before. Suddenly started getting this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add this to your pub spec

```
dependencies:
  flex_color_picker: 2.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution which @Hooman said we can use.

And please go through the following links too.

https://github.com/rydmike/flex_color_picker/issues/40

https://github.com/tneotia/html-editor-enhanced/issues/225